# Seems a bug of member access in a default template-argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider such two variance examples

#### [Example #1](https://godbolt.org/z/9c7xYzPT7)

```cpp
struct A{
    template<class T, int R>
    friend void show();

private:
    int c;
};

template<class T, int R = decltype(T{}.c){0} >
void show(){
}

int main(){
  show<A>();
}
```

#### [Example #2](https://godbolt.org/z/1fK1Pdxj4)

```cpp
struct A{
    template<class T, int R>
    friend void show();

private:
    int c;
};

template<class T, int R = decltype(A{}.c){0} >
void show(){
}

int main(){
    show<A>();
}
```

Clang accepts `#2` and rejects `#1`:

```
<source>:14:3: error: no matching function for call to 'show'
  show<A>();
  ^~~~~~~
<source>:10:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = A, R = 0]: 'c' is a private member of 'A'
void show(){
     ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:14:3: error: no matching function for call to 'show'
  show<A>();
  ^~~~~~~
<source>:10:6: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = A, R = 0]: 'c' is a private member of 'A'
void show(){
     ^
```

However, according to [class.access.general] p9 and [class.access.general] p6, such two examples should all be well-formed

> Access for a default template-argument ([temp.param]) **is checked in the context in which it appears rather than at any points of use of it**.
>
> All access controls in [class.access] affect the ability to name a class member from the declaration of a particular entity, **including parts of the declaration preceding the name of the entity being declared** and, if the entity is a class, the definitions of members of the class appearing outside the class's member-specification.

Since the template function `show` is a friend of class `A`, hence the private member of `A` is also accessible in the part preceding the name of the entity(`show`) being declared, and the access of the default template-argument is checked in this context where it appears. It should be all fine. Is any rule that has an otherwise specification? If not, Is it considered a bug of Clang?

Comment: Well, [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/T8ac8P3e4) rejects both.

Comment: @Bob__  I think GCC has no reason to reject either case.

Comment: I can get GCC to work by forward declaring `show()`: https://godbolt.org/z/Gv6hrK9dh.  But Clang continues to give the same error.

Comment: @cmannett85 That also be a bug of GCC. "forward declaring" shouldn't affect the program.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So this is still an active issue [[CWG1699]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1699), with status *drafting*: *"Informal consensus has been reached in the working group and is described in rough terms in a Tentative Resolution, although precise wording for the change is not yet available."*.

Comment: _«including parts of the declaration preceding the name of the entity being declared»_ In [_template-declaration_](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.pre#nt:template-declaration), _template-head_ is not part of _declaration_.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer [temp.pre] p3 says: A template-declaration is a *declaration*, the entity befriended is the function template, the definition in the first example is exactly declaring that entity, so the template-head is the part of that declaration. Otherwise, the second example should also be ill-formed.

Comment: Surprisingly that MSVC accepts even completely unrelated friend declaration as valid: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YETaG3786